# Keyvault Authentication using username and password

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

The customer has created a key vault and store the credentials . To authenticate key vault , I have created the application in the node and using client id and client secret , I am able to read the secrets. But now the customer wants not to use the client id and client secret , instead use the username and password of the AZURE to access the keyvault in the program. Its one dedicated user for the keyvault access with no MFA.

I am not sure if we can access the keyvault with username and password from the node js. Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find out the reason the customer wants it like this? To me this sounds extremely stupid and I would refuse to do this unless the client can provide a seriously good explanation.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token They want to use this username/password authentication

Comment: So do they want your app to access the Key Vault as the currently signed in user or a fixed user account? A fixed user account makes no sense to me with no advantage over an application using a client id and secret. Have they told you the reason _why_ they want to do this?

Comment: I've learned the client never really knows what they want. They know what they *think* they want, though. It's up to the developer to steer them in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this requirement, I also think that use username-password flow is unnecessary and client credential flow should be better (as juunas mentioned in comments). But if the customer still want to use username-password flow to implement, I can provide a sample as below for your reference:

**1.** You should register an app in AD with native platform but not web platform.
[image]
[image]

And please check if "**Treat application as a public client**" is enabled.
[image]

If your app is web platform, when you run the node js code it will show error message to ask you provide "client secret" even if you use username-password flow.

**2.** You need to add the azure key vault permission to your app.
[image]
[image]
And do not forget grant admin consent for it.

**3.** Then you can refer to the code below to get the secret value.

```
const KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
const { AuthenticationContext } = require('adal-node');

const clientId = '<clientId>';
const username = '<username>';
const password = '<password>';
var secretAuthenticator = function (challenge, callback) {
    var context = new AuthenticationContext(challenge.authorization);
    return context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword(challenge.resource, username, password, clientId, function(
        err,
        tokenResponse,
    ) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var authorizationValue = tokenResponse.tokenType + ' ' + tokenResponse.accessToken;
        return callback(null, authorizationValue);
    });
};

var credentials = new KeyVault.KeyVaultCredentials(secretAuthenticator);
var client = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);
client.getSecret("https://<keyvaultname>.vault.azure.net/", "<secret name>", "<secret version>", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("secret value is: " + result.value);
});
```